# Why shouldn't I use compound class in xpath when it works fine?

Tags: xpath

I've written three different xpaths to serve a particular purpose. The three of them are working just fine. However, I'm seriously dubious at this point thinking which one to choose cause they all are giving the same result in this particular case. I expected to know the dos and don'ts. Thanks in advance.

```
import requests
from lxml import html

page = requests.get('https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=pizza&geo_location_terms=Los+Angeles%2C+CA').text
tree = html.fromstring(page)
for row in tree.xpath('//div[@class="info"]'):
    Phone = row.xpath('.//div[@class="phones phone primary"]/text()')
    Phone1 = row.xpath('.//div[contains(@class,"phones")]/text()')
    Phone2 = row.xpath(".//div[contains(concat(' ',@class,' '),' phones ')]/text()")
    print (Phone, Phone1, Phone2)
```

Comment: If the 3 XPath expressions give the same result in this case, but will give different results in other cases, then to know which is "correct" we need to know what other cases might arise, and there's no way we can help you know that, except perhaps if we have detailed familiarity with the HTML design at yellowpages.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

div[@class="phones phone primary"] works but would fail if you had class="primary phones phone". The latter is functionally identical in the browser but, obviously, a different string.

div[contains(@class,"phones")] does not delimit the text so it would also  match class="definatelynophonesever"

Ideally, you want a space delimited entry to match classes in the middle but there is no space at the front or after the last one - hence adding spaces in the last path:

```
.//div[contains(concat(' ',@class,' '),' phones ')]
```

This will always work for any class that contains a single word "phones" anywhere in the class attribute.

Comment: Thanks Mike for your answer. Now it makes sense to me. Would you be benevolent enough to update the last xpath with it's proper format so that i can follow as my one is faulty. Thanks again for the clarity.

Comment: I've put it in code tags, but it's exactly the same as your last example - Phone2. I've also run it through xsltproc and it seems to parse fine and select the right nodes.

Comment: Thanks Mike for everything.